# Hibernate HQL delete query

Tags: hibernate, hql, hql-delete

Im looking for information but I didnt find how.

I have two tables:

- Remesas

> ```
> |codigo_prod|  nombre   |codigo_proveedor|
> -----------------------------------------
> |    1001   | product1  |     EST        |
> |    1002   | product2  |     ASM        |
>
> - Proveedores 
>
> |codigo_proveedor|  mail         |
> ----------------------------------
> |    EST        | pro@mail.com  |
> |    ASM        | pro2@mail.com |  
> |    DAM        | pro3@mail.com |
> ```

I have to delete from Proveedores the row that dont have codigo_proveedor on Remesas
in this case delete DAM that its not on Remesas.

Thank you!

Comment: I didnt understand your tables but you can write any query you want with `session.CreateSQLQuery(YorQueryString)` method.

Comment: Maybe you can understand It better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    Session s= HibernateUtil.getSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    s.CreateSQLQuery("delete Proveedores where codigo_proveedor not in 
                      (select codigo_proveedor from Remesas)");
    s.getTransaction().commit();
```

I know it for Java!

Comment: Throw me that error:
node to traverse cannot be null! Maybe thats why this is SQL not HQL?

Comment: I changed it with Elbek Query. I think this should works

Comment: Sorry was problem of my database It worked! THank you :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
    delete Proveedores pr  where pr.codigo_proveedor not in 
                      (select re.codigo_proveedor from Remesas re)
```